# Hard edged shadows?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, light

I have a model textured and every time I put Blender into Rendered View, these weird hard edged shadows show up as if I have vertices sticking out but they are clean.

[image]

Could this be a shadow settings problem or is it likely something to do with the texturing? I'm using the cycles rendering engine.

A copy of the ~.blend file can be downloaded from https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=322

Comment: Looks like z-fighting to me.  Do you have another object underneath this one?

Comment: No object underneath on the same layer. Other layers shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Right, other layers (as long as they are not visible) don't matter.  Is there any duplicated geometry at those parts of the mesh?  I am pretty sure what you are experiencing is z-fighting (the artifacts produced when two faces are occupying the exact same plane).

Comment: Would it be possible to upload your .blend to a site like [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we could take a look?

Comment: Is your mesh similarly shaded across the boundary that you are identifying as "hard shadows? I can reproduce a very similar effect by setting the whole mesh to "smooth" face shading in the "shading panel" of the UV / Face tab, except for a couple of faces set to "flat".

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=322" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/322/)
Here it is.

Comment: Its not that. The whole thing seems to to have smooth shading